# Difference between "A" and "it"

Tags: grammar

Can anyone please tell me if I should use **a** or **it** in the following sentence?

Here's my sentence:

> For years, I have been searching for a good job but after years have passed I still have not found ***it***.

or

> For years, I have been searching for a good job but after years have passed I still have not found ***a good job***.

I think **it** is wrong.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between "I still have not found it." and "I still have not found a good job." or about whether you can say "I still have not found *it* good job"?

Comment: @stangdon Hi I want to know in that sentence if I should say "I still haven't found a good job" or "I still haven't found it". I think "it" sounds wrong. I know I can say "I still haven't one." But my question is between the above two, which one is correct?

Comment: Since you used the *indefinite* article when you first specified what you've been searching for *(**a** good job)*, the implication is that there are many potential good jobs that might suit you. So you should say *I still have not found **one***, not ***it***. Because you presumably only want one good job, you should say that. If you were talking about something you might want several of, it would be *I've been searching for **good clothes**,* [plural] *but I haven't been able to find **any***.

Comment: **It** is perfectly grammatically correct and sounds fine to this US English speaker; *it* is just a reference to the a thing you were talking about earlier ("a good job").  But as FumbleFingers says, it might be more fluent to say *one*, since you're not talking about a specific job.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you both of you. Is "I still have not found a good job." also correct?

Comment: @user254288: *I still have not found a good job* is "grammatical", but it's hopelessly non-idiomatic in your exact context to repeat ***a good job*** like that in a single sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think I can also say "I still have not found any." Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say

> I've been searching for **my dream job** but still haven't found **it**.

or

> I've been searching for **a job** where unpaid overtime isn't expected, but it's hard to find **one** in this industry.

or

> I've been searching for **jobs** in that city which are a decent match for my skills and experience but I haven't found **any** yet.